# Find location of the largest sum in 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, area

So lets say I have a an array that looks similar to this :

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I would like to return the location of the center of the largest sum of values within a certain n*n square. So in this case it would be (2,2) if n = 3. If I let n = 4 it would be the same result.

Does numpy have a method for finding this location?

Comment: if `n` was `4`, wouldn't there be `2` problems: there is no centre `index` and in your `example`, all convolutions would have the same `sum`... No?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** We can use [SciPy's  `2D` convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) to get summations in sliding windows of shape `(n,n)` and choose the index of the window with the biggest sum with `argmax` and translate to row, col indices with `np.unravel_index`, like so -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

def largest_sum_pos_app1(a, n):
    idx = conv2(a, np.ones((n,n),dtype=int),'same').argmax()
    return np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [558]: a
Out[558]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [559]: largest_sum_pos_app1(a, n=3)
Out[559]: (2, 2)
```

**Approach #1S (Super charged) :** We can boost it further by using [`uniform filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter.html), like so -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter as unif2D

def largest_sum_pos_app1_mod1(a, n):
    idx = unif2D(a.astype(float),size=n, mode='constant').argmax()
    return np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
```

**Approach #2 :** Another based on `scikit-image`'s sliding window creating tool [`view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows), we would create sliding windows of shape `(n,n)` to give us a `4D` array with the last two axes of shape `(n,n)` corresponding to the search window size. So, we would sum along those two axes and get the `argmax` index and translate it to the actual row, col positions.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def largest_sum_pos_app2(a, n):
    h = (n-1)//2 # half window size
    idx = view_as_windows(a, (n,n)).sum((-2,-1)).argmax()
    return tuple(np.array(np.unravel_index(idx, np.array(a.shape)-n+1))+h)
```

As also mentioned in the comments, a search square with an even `n` would be confusing given that it won't have its center at any element coordinate.

**Runtime test**

```
In [741]: np.random.seed(0)

In [742]: a = np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000,1000))

In [743]: largest_sum_pos_app1(a, n= 5)
Out[743]: (966, 403)

In [744]: largest_sum_pos_app1_mod1(a, n= 5)
Out[744]: (966, 403)

In [745]: largest_sum_pos_app2(a, n= 5)
Out[745]: (966, 403)

In [746]: %timeit largest_sum_pos_app1(a, n= 5)
     ...: %timeit largest_sum_pos_app1_mod1(a, n= 5)
     ...: %timeit largest_sum_pos_app2(a, n= 5)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 57.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 47.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you, it works for what I needed it to work for however, is there another method that I can apply using slicing and loops and potentially dictionaries?

Comment: @ASK Should be straight-forward with loops. Give that a try. Not really good with dictionaries.

Comment: okay I tried it a few different ways but I don't seem to be able to store or sum up the values. the other problem I have is I don't know how to create an array of a certain n*n size that will iterate over the given array that I'm trying to find the location of the data in. can you chime in?

Comment: @ASK Maybe ask a new question specifically saying you need to use dictionaries/loops only. Though that would defeat the purpose of using NumPy, which is performance. Why do you need to use loops/dictionaries, when vectorized methods as suggested would be faster?

Comment: Because I'm curious to see how it works, since that is the method I tried doing originally.

Comment: Any way to do this with a 3D array/window?